# What is the relationship with index in glBindBufferBase() and stream number in geometry shader in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to transform data from geometry shaders to feedback buffer,so I set the names of variables like this:

```
char *Varying[] = {"lColor","lPos","gl_NextBuffer","rColor","rPos"};
```

then bind two buffers `vbos[2]` to transformFeedback object `Tfb`,`vbos[0]` to bind point 0, and `vbos[1]` to bind point 2:

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, vbos[0]);
glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 2, vbos[1]);
```

and set stream number like this:

```
layout(stream=0) out vec4 lColor;
layout(stream=0) out vec4 lPos;

layout(stream = 2) out rVert
{
    vec4 rColor;
    vec4 rPos;
};
```

So I thought  `lColor` and `lPos` are transformed to `vbos[0]`,`rColor` and `rPos` are transformed to `vbos[1]`,but nothing came out,unless I change `vbos[1]` to bind point 1,and stream number of `rvert` to 1.

I think there is three variables about indexes for binding geometry shader output and feedback buffers,first is `index` in `glBindBufferBase(target,index,id)`,second is sequences of names in `glTransformFeedbackVaryings(program,count,names,buffermode)`,third is stream number of variables in geometry shader,what is the relationship of these three parameters?
And I found that no matter what parameters I set the `glDrawTransformFeedbackStream` ,picture didn't change,Why?

Comment: Until now,from my test,there can't be any empty bind point of feedback object.If a feedback buffer is bound to index 0,next feedback buffer must be bound to index 1.But I still don't understand the relationship between stream index and bind index of glBindBufferBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry shader layout qualifier `stream` has no direct relationship to the TF buffer binding index assignment. There is one caveat here: variables from two different streams can't be assigned to the same buffer binding index. But aside from that, the two have no relationship.

In geometry shader transform feedback, streams are written independently of each other. When you output a vertex/primitive, you say which stream the GS invocation is writing. Only the output variables assigned to that stream are written, and the system keeps track of how much stuff has been written to each stream.

But how the output variables map to feedback buffers is entirely separate (aside from the aforementioned caveat).

In your example, `glTransformFeedbackVaryings` with `{"lColor","lPos","gl_NextBuffer","rColor","rPos"}` does the following. It starts with buffer index 0. It assigns `lColor` and `lPos` to buffer index 0. `gl_NextBuffer` causes the system to increment the value of the current buffer index. That value is 0, so incrementing it makes it 1. It then assigns `rColor`  and `rPos` to buffer 1.

That's why your code doesn't work.

You can skip buffer indices in the TF buffer bindings. To do that, you have to use `gl_NextBuffer` *twice*, since each use increments the current buffer index.

Or if your GL version is high enough, you can just [assign the buffer bindings and offsets directly in your shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback#In-shader_specification):

```
layout(stream=0, xfb_offset = 0, xfb_buffer = 0) out vec4 lColor;
layout(stream=0, xfb_offset = 16, xfb_buffer = 0) out vec4 lPos;

layout(stream = 2, xfb_offset = 0, xfb_buffer = 2) out rVert
{
    vec4 rColor;
    vec4 rPos;
};
```

Comment: I tried the first method by adding a `gl_NextBuffer`, find that if I skip TF bind index 1 ,just bind BO to index 0,and 2,there will be system err.Even skip index 1,still need to bind a BO to this index.And I tried your second method,I got a 'xfb_offset : syntax error', my GLSL version is core 430,can you help me with this,thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Oh, another thing, I want to draw TF like this: first,`glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);` and `glDrawTransformFeedbackStream(GL_TRIANGLES, Tfb, 0);`,second `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);` and `glDrawTransformFeedbackStream(GL_TRIANGLES, Tfb, 1);`, so stream output 0 is fill mode,stream output 1 is line mode,if I switch the stream indexes of `glDrawTransformFeedbackStream`,it stay the same,I thought these two would change places,why?

Comment: @Chris: "*my GLSL version is core 430,*" As stated in the link, you need GLSL 4.40. As for the rest, you never say what this "system err" is. Lastly, you don't have a "stream output 1"; you explicitly skipped it and used stream 2. So when you draw stream 1, I'm guessing it draws no vertices.